# How to check response for multiple requests in ASINetworkQueue?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using ASINetworkQueue to send multiple requests to the server one after another. I have 4 consecutive server calls.

I want to know whenever the response is received, I want to handle it in selector for queue. I  have implemented handler method as well using

```
requestDidFinishSelector
```

I want to know how to get responsestring for each request individually?  just like

```
[request responseString]
```

with normal http requests? How can I solve this? `Thanks in advance.`

Comment: I can see the selector method is called 4 times - once for each request, but im not finding a way to differentiate between different response strings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved : solution found [here](https://gist.github.com/pokeb/150447) in github itself

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
  {

       //print or manipulate response here

 }
```